# How to add a foreign key with references to a table which will be create in the next line

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Departament
(d_nume varchar(30), d_nr int, manager varchar(30), PRIMARY KEY(d_nr), 
FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES Angajat(nume));


CREATE TABLE Angajat
(nume varchar(30), prenume varchar(30), cnp char(13), d_nr int, PRIMARY KEY(cnp), 
FOREIGN KEY(d_nr) REFERENCES Departament(d_nr));
```

"Cannot add foreign key constraint"

I use this editor online http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: A table has to be created before you can add the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

When two tables reference each other, you can use `alter table`:

```
CREATE TABLE Departament (
    d_nr int,
    d_nume varchar(30),
    manager char(13), 
    PRIMARY KEY (d_nr)
);

CREATE TABLE Angajat (
    cnp char(13),
    nume varchar(30),
    prenume varchar(30),
    d_nr int,
    PRIMARY KEY(cnp),
    FOREIGN KEY(d_nr) REFERENCES Departament(d_nr)
);

ALTER TABLE Departament ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES Angajat(cnp);
```

Foreign key references should also be to the primary key, which I normally make the first column in a table.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b87a803) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Isn't that going to be a horrible circular reference?

Comment: @P.Salmon . . . Not at all.  A department has a manager who is an employee.  Employees are in a department.  This seems reasonable.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it is reasonale but you cannot insert into department before you insert into angajat and you can't do that before you insert into department.

Comment: @GabrielPinţă . . . Look at the SQL Fiddle.  The code works.

Comment: yes it works, but when i want to INSERT INTO this 2 tables i can't. Here is the message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_9_b36720`.`departament`, CONSTRAINT `departament_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manager`) REFERENCES `angajat` (`cnp`))

Comment: @P.Salmon: The foreign key in Gordon's code has no `NOT NULL` constraint on it. So you can insert into both tables with a `NULL` value for the foreign key and later update the foreign key.

Comment: @GabrielPinţă . . . That is a new question.  You should ask it as a *question* not in a comment.